# undeclared identifiers already declared?

Tags: c, visual-studio-2010, undeclared-identifier

I'm working on a problem for school and I'm getting "undeclared identifier" in every line with my suitsInHand or facesInHand arrays. The last time this happened was because I wasn't declaring my variables at the top of the block, but as far as I can tell this isn't happening for the same reason. Can anyone tell me what I've done wrong?

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

#define SUITS 4
#define FACES 13
#define AVAILABLE 0
#define TAKEN 1

void dealACard(char *suits[], char *faces[], int deck[][FACES]);
void dealAHand(char *suits[], char *faces[], int deck[][FACES]);
void analyzeHand(char *suits[], char *faces[]);

int main(void){
    int suitsInHand[4] = {0};
    int facesInHand[13] = {0};
    char *suits[4] = {"Hearts", "Diamonds", "Spades", "Clubs"};
    char *faces[13] = {"Two", "Three", "Four", "Five", "Six", "Seven", "Eight", "Nine", "Ten", "Jack", "Queen", "King", "Ace"};
    int deck[4][13] = {AVAILABLE};

    srand(time(NULL));
    dealAHand(suits, faces, deck);

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}

void dealAHand(char *suits[], char *faces[], int deck[][FACES]){
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<5;i++)
        dealACard(suits,faces,deck);
}

void dealACard(char *suits[], char *faces[], int deck[][FACES]){
    int suitIndex, faceIndex;
    memset(suitsInHand, 0, sizeof(suitsInHand));
    memset(facesInHand, 0, sizeof(facesInHand));

    suitIndex = rand() % 4;
    faceIndex = rand() % 13;
    while (deck[suitIndex][faceIndex]==TAKEN){
        suitIndex = rand() % 4;
        faceIndex = rand() % 13;
    }
    deck[suitIndex][faceIndex]=TAKEN;
    suitsInHand[suitIndex]++;
    facesInHand[faceIndex]++;

    printf("%s of %s.\n", faces[faceIndex], suits[suitIndex]);
}

void analyzeHand(char *suits[], char *faces[]){
    typedef enum {false, true} bool;
    int num_consec = 0;
    int rank, suit;
    bool straight = false;
    bool flush = false;
    bool four = false;
    bool three = false;
    int pairs = 0;

    for(suit=0;suit<SUITS;suit++)
        if(suitsInHand[suit]==5)
            flush = true;

    rank = 0;
    while (facesInHand[rank]==0)
        rank++;

    //for(;rank<FACES && facesInHand[rank]; rank++)
    //  num_consec++;

    if(num_consec == 5){
        straight = true;
        return;
    }

    for(rank = 0;rank<NUM_RANKS; rank++){
        if(facesInHand[rank]==4)
            four = true;
        if(facesInHand[rank]==3)
            three = true;
        if(facesInHand[rank]==2)
            pairs++;
    }

    if(straight == true && flush == true)
        printf("Straight flush.\n\n");
    else if(four == true)
        printf("Four of a kind.\n\n");
    else if(three == true && pairs == 1)
        printf("Full house.\n\n");
    else if(flush == true)
        printf("Flush.\n\n");
    else if(straight == true)
        printf("Straight.\n\n");
    else if(three == true)
        printf("Three of a kind.\n\n");
    else if(pairs == 2)
        printf("Two pairs.\n\n");
    else if(pairs == 1)
        printf("Pair.\n\n");
    else
        printf("High card.\n\n");


}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here:

```
void dealACard(char *suits[], char *faces[], int deck[][FACES]){
    int suitIndex, faceIndex;
    memset(suitsInHand, 0, sizeof(suitsInHand));
```

`suitsInHand` is not declared in this scope. `suitsInHand` is declared in the scope of `main` function not in `dealACard` scope.

To fix this, you can add a parameter to your functions to pass `suitsInHand` or declare `suitsInHand` at file scope.

The same applies for `facesInHand`.

Answer (score 1):

youve declared `suitsInHand` in main,  but that doesnt mean its available to other functions,  you need to pass it to other functions for them to have access to it.

you are getting to the point where you are passing quite a few things around that you should put them into a struct and then pass the struct around.

Also, in general, your dealACard function is potentially very very nasty.  Especially if there is only 1 card in the deck, it might take a very long time to get the right random number to deal the last card in the deck

Comment: I haven't started on structs yet, but I'll look into it. Thank you.